# Wrapper(s) for Cloudfoundry VCAP_SERVICE in Java?

Tags: java, json, cloud-foundry

Working with the VCAP_SERVICE [environment variable](https://support.appfog.com/hc/en-us/articles/202315666-Working-with-VCAP-SERVICES-Environment-Variables) `(java.lang.System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES")` requires handling a JSON String, that could have a quite elaborate structure - but following a predictable pattern.

Is there a commonly used helper class around, that does the JSON parsing for easy access to the variables? (I know how to parse raw JSON, so I'm looking for a CF specific one that hat nice getters to read the variables).

I found [a project](https://github.com/hmalphettes/cloudfoundry-vcapservices-java-helper) that hasn't been updated in 3 years - **is that the library to use**? Or would one use the [CF Client lib](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/blob/master/cloudfoundry-client-lib/src/main/java/org/cloudfoundry/client/lib/util/CloudEntityResourceMapper.java)?

Ideally it would be something like:

```
   VCapService config = new VCapService();
   String somevar = config.get("/user-provided/special/test","default-if-no-cloud");
```

I'm not picky about the query (above is a little like URI or XPath).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Cloud Connectors is what you want: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors.

In spite of the name, the core Spring Cloud Connectors library does not depend on the Spring Framework, but is a plain old Java library. See the documentation here on using the core of the library to get an object model parsed from VCAP_SERVICES: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/tree/master/spring-cloud-core#spring-cloud-core.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to develop your application to be dependent on Cloud Foundry (such as wrapping and transforming the VCAP_SERVICES inside your application). Instead you can parse the VCAP_SERVICES before you start your application and transform it into easier to read environment variables. Here is an example by using a tool called [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (command-line JSON processor):

```
MNG=$(echo $VCAP_SERVICES | jq '.mongodb[0].credentials.uri')
export MONGO_URL=$(echo $MNG | cut -d "\"" -f 2)
```

You can put this two liner in your start script before your application has been started and it will transform the VCAP_SERVICES into a "light" & digestible environment variable.

Comment: I actually struggled with this issue because I wanted my application to always connect to a database defined in an environment variable, no matter in which environment it runs. At first I wanted to mimic the pretty complex structure of VCAP_SERVICES in order to not modify my code but parsing the relevant part out of the JSON object and sticking it in a plain old env variable is probably the way better approach. +1 for that!